# App crashed at textview.becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard-events

My app sometimes crashes at the call to `textView.becomeFirstResponder()`. The error thrown is strange:

```
-[UITextSelectionView keyboardShownWithNotif:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16899070
```

Sometimes it's:

```
-[UIImageView keyboardShownWithNotif:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178e2610
```

I did add notification listeners:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShown(notif:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHidden), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

But the observer is the custom view I defined, why does the system send notification to `UITextSelectionView` or `UIImageView`?

Found in iOS 8.4.1, not reproduced in iOS 9.

What is happening here?

Comment: Where did you get that code from?

Comment: what u have written in delegate method of textfiew/textfield

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seems like you added an notif. observer to show/hide keyboard. 
Try to remove observer in dealloc method

 - (void) dealloc {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; //Or whichever observer you want to remove
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}
```

or

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}
```