# NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow crash - Unable to find cause

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, crashlytics

Users of my app have reported a random crash. I have integrated CrashAnalytics which is giving the following details :

```
__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20.
```

[image]

The line number indicated is 154, which is :

```
self.notesView.content.frame = CGRect(x: self.notesView.content.frame.origin.x, y: self.notesView.content.frame.origin.y, width: self.notesView.content.frame.size.width, height: self.notesView.content.frame.size.height - keyboardFrame.size.height).
```

Following is the code I have written which consist of this line :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        label_title.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShown), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil);
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHide), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil);
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        label_title.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        self.notesView.content.frame = CGRect(x: self.notesView.content.frame.origin.x, y: self.notesView.content.frame.origin.y, width: self.notesView.content.frame.size.width, height: self.notesView.content.frame.size.height - keyboardFrame.size.height)
    }
```

Firstly, this is quite random and I never get it. Secondly, I am not able to find exact cause for it. Is this because of notification observer or because of notesView (which is not nil).
As suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601357/app-crashed-at-textview-becomefirstresponder), should I remove keyboard notification observer in deinit ?
Please guide me through this if someone has experienced this previously.

Comment: The proper Swift 3 and ObjC compatible syntax of the notification selector is `func keyboardShown(_ notification: Notification)`- note the underscore.

Comment: @vadian : would that really matter ?

Comment: Update noteview frame inside  DispatchQueue.main.async {notesView.content...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change signature of your function to this

```
@objc func keyboardShown(_ notification: Notification)
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why @objc works? I am facing similar crash but unable to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why adding `@objc` to the function works?

Comment: The cause is the upgrade from swift 3 to swift 4 that needs @objc for selectors

Comment: saved my night :)