# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS in Swift and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, crash, crashlytics

I just launched the app and I have an issue with iPhone 5 and 5c and iOS 10.3.3 (only).

[image]

I really don't understand the problem, even with the Crashlytics report:

[image]

The problem seems to come from this line:

```
@objc UserProfilViewController.collectionView(UICollectionView, layout : UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath : IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

This is my code:

```
// Cell size
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

      let size: CGSize
      if cellIsNull == false {
         size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.47, height: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.47)
      } else {
         size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.47)
      }
      return size
   }
```

If I run the app on the simulator (with an iPhone 5), the app is not crashing, and I don't have iPhone 5 so I don't test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it a coincidence. I asked a [**similar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478802/nsnotification-name-uikeyboardwillshow-crash-unable-to-find-cause) question few hours back. Not same but similar.
The solution is to put `@objc` in front of function definition. So function should be like :

```
@objc func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { 
....  

}
```

The main thing to notice is that the crash is random. I myself haven't received this yet. There might be a possibility that it depends on the iOS or indirectly, Swift version.

Comment: Do you have any idea why @objc works? I am facing a similar crash and cannot reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why adding `@objc` to the function works?